# ⌃⇧L 'Wrap selection/word as a link' broken in TextMate

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

I regularly use ⌃⇧L in TextMate to wrap selection as a link. When I used it this morning, i got...

```
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n'
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when %r{http://www.(amazon.(?:com...
          ^
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:15: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when %r{\A[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*://.*\z}:
          ^
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:17: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:19: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when %r{\A(www\..*|.*\.(com|uk|net|org|info))\z}:
          ^
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:19: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when %r{\A.*\.(com|uk|net|org|info)\z}:
          ^
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:21: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
      when %r{\A\S+\z}:
          ^
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:23: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:27: warning: else without rescue is useless
    /tmp/temp_textmate.RRepHN:28: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting
```

I can't think of anything specific I might have done to cause the issue.

I have reloaded bundles and reinstalled TextMate.

I also tried using the code at http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Hyperlink%20Helper.tmbundle/Commands/Wrap%20Selection%20as%20Link.tmCommand.

None of them fixed the problem.

Anyone have any ideas?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a colon at the `when ...` line. You can edit the snippet and remove it in the Bundle Editor.

Comment: Precise, concise... and it fixed the problem. Brilliant! Thanks. Only question left, which doesn't need to be answered, is where did the colons came from?! :)

Comment: @petedickson: I believe Ruby 1.8 and prior allowed you to use a colon in place of the keyword `then` in one-line `when` statements, but this is no longer allowed in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Ahhh, so, when I started using 1.9.2 as standard on my system instead of 1.8.7... it stopped working! Thanks for the explanation. If I could vote you up, I would!

Comment: just wondering if you could shed any light on http://stackoverflow.com/q/5429097/642039. Cool if you can, if not, no bad!