# ⌃⇧H in TextMate to 'Tidy' HTML causes NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, textmate, tidy, textmatebundles

I tried using 'Tidy' in an HTML document for the first time yesterday, and got...

```
/tmp/temp_textmate.Z2P0KX:30:in `<main>': undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I've not done anything to the code in the bundle...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/ui.rb'
require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/exit_codes.rb'

result = `"${TM_TIDY:-tidy}" -f /tmp/tm_tidy_errors -iq -utf8 \
          -wrap 0 --tab-size $TM_TAB_SIZE --indent-spaces $TM_TAB_SIZE \
        --indent yes \
          ${TM_XHTML:+-asxhtml --output-xhtml yes} \
          ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:+--show-body-only yes} \
          --enclose-text yes \
          --doctype strict \
        --wrap-php no \
          --tidy-mark no`
status = $?.exitstatus

at_exit { File.unlink('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors') } # Clean up error log

if status == 2 # Errors

  msg = "Errors: " + File.read('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors')
  TextMate.exit_show_tool_tip msg

elsif status == 1 # Warnings - use output but also display notification with warnings

  log = File.read('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors').to_a.select do |line|
    ! (ENV['TM_SELECTED_TEXT'] and (line.include?('Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration') or line.include?("Warning: inserting missing 'title' element")))
  end.join rescue nil

  unless log.empty?
    options = {
      :title   => "Tidy Warnings",
      :summary => "Warnings for tidying your document (press escape to close):",
      :log     => log
    }
    TextMate::UI.simple_notification(options)
  end

end

if ENV['TM_SOFT_TABS'] == "YES"
  print result
else
  in_pre = false
  result.each_line do |line|
    unless in_pre
      tab_size = ENV["TM_TAB_SIZE"].to_i
      space, text = /( *)(.*)/m.match(line)[1..2]
      line = "\t" * (space.length / tab_size).floor + " "  * (space.length % tab_size) + text
    end

    print line

    in_pre = true  if line.include?("<pre>")
    in_pre = false if line.include?("</pre>")
  end
end
```

The problem line is `unless log.empty?`.

I'm running TextMate 1.5.10 (1631) on OS X 10.6.6. I recently installed rvm and upgraded default Ruby to 1.9.2, though forcing TextMate to use 1.8.7 did not fix the problem.

Comment: Is that up-arrow in your title deliberate?!?

Comment: @slugster, yes, it's deliberate as that's Ctrl-Shift-H is the default key equivalent for Tidy in TextMate. Regarding the problem, I just tested it out locally and had no problem with it, but as the command is written in Ruby, you might try adding the Ruby tag to this question. I don't know Ruby well enough to be able to be more assistance. As far as I can tell, my version of the command is identical to yours. Since the error is occurring while checking for warnings, my guess is that there's something wrong with the Tidy installation.

Comment: @Chuck - thanks. I've added the 'ruby' tag as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I have setup my Textmate to use the RVM version of ruby so that I can quickly test scripts.

I solved the problem by unchecking the "TM_RUBY" for the environment variable I had created.

What appears to be happening is the Textmate scripts that wrapper the /usr/bin/tidy command are not executing properly when using a ruby version other than the one that ships with OSX.

I'm curious to see what happens when Lion comes out. Hopefully, Textmate will take another look at these build-in scripts and give them a little "dusting-off".

Comment: Would have been great. Except they didn't. Three years later and the problem persists. C'mon: an super powerful text editor and you can not use it as soon as you install software using brew or macports? Sad...

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the assignment to `log`, you'll see this:

```
log = File.read('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors').to_a.select do |line| ... end.join rescue nil
```

The `rescue nil` at the end will put a `nil` into `log` if the `/tmp/tm_tidy_errors` file isn't there or it can't be read or what ever. Then the script will call the `.empty?` method on `nil` but the `nil` object has no such method and the script falls over and dies.

You can suppress the problem by changing `rescue nil` to `rescue ''` or by changing `unless log.empty?` to `unless log.nil? || log.empty?` but that might not be the real problem.

Do you have a `TM_TIDY` environment variable set? Is there a `tidy` command in your `PATH`? Looks like your Tidy install isn't right (or possible not there at all). My OSX has `/usr/bin/tidy` and apparently that's standard. Try running that big `tidy` command by hand in a terminal and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too, on a machine running OS X 10.9.5 with Ruby upgraded to ruby 2.0.0. Fixed it by taking mu is too short's suggestion to change `unless log.empty?` to `unless long.nil? || log.empty?`. That allowed Tidy to run properly, but the top of my HTML selection was still showing me annoying errors:

```
ruby: warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/ui.rb:129: warning: assigned but unused variable - pid
```

I shut that up by changing the first line of the script from `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU -W0`. Obviously the problems are still there under the hood, but for something helpful but not essential, as this functionality is, I think it's plenty good enough.